# How to check if a certain option is checked in my google form with apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

What I am attempting to do as a whole, is once someone has submitted a form,  they will be sent an email (google doc) depending on which option they chose from "checkboxes" on my google form.

The response of that option is logged as follows: [a, c, d]

I got this far. I am not sure how I can take this response as a whole and check for 1 option independantly.

Here is my code so  far:

```
var EMAIL_TEMPLATE_DOC_URL = 'x';

function sendEmail(e) {
  var responses = e.namedValues;

  var recipient_name = responses['What is your full name?']
  var recipient_email = responses['Email address'][0].trim()
  var recipient_classes = responses['Which classes are you interested in attending?']

  Logger.log(recipient_classes)

  // What do you want the subject of the email to be?
  var email_subject = `${recipient_name} here are your class details!` 
  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: recipient_email,
    subject: email_subject,
    htmlBody: createEmailBody(),
  })

}

function createEmailBody() {
  // Make sure to update the emailTemplateDocId at the top.
  var docId = DocumentApp.openByUrl(EMAIL_TEMPLATE_DOC_URL).getId();
  var emailBody = docToHtml(docId);
  return emailBody;
}

function docToHtml(docId) {
  // Downloads a Google Doc as an HTML string.
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=' +
            docId + '&exportFormat=html';
  var param = {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, param).getContentText();
}
```

[image: Form options]
Loggler.log(recipient_classes) = [a, c, d]

I want to check if A is checked OR B is checked, OR C is checked, etc.

I can figure out a way to hard check if each combination of the options is selected... but I want it to be able to go through the list and check search for a certain term. It sounds like it would be something easy to code but I have been stuck for so long.

Comment: Can you expand the statement `I got this far. I am not sure how I can take this response as a whole and check for 1 option independantly.`? I'm unsure if you're just looking for something like an [`if...else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) statement combined with [`loops and iteration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) or if you'd like to permutate the results based on what the user selects.

Comment: The event object for Spreadsheets is much different and the values array return a timestamp in the first element and then it returns the answers to all of the questions in the order they appear on the form.  namedValues associates the questions as object properties to the answers.

Comment: @Saddles , if what though. I got as far as being able to send an email and get which boxes he checked. But how do I check if X is part of that list of options that he checked. Remember X can be in the first position of the list or the last position of the list, how do I loop through all the options and check for each one. 
Option he choose looks like this: [a, b, c, d] it is NOT an array (i dont think it is atleast), when I log the length of this I get length of 2.0. Not sure it its a list or what. To restate, if I had 5 options potentially to be selected. A, B, C, D, E. how do i check for C?

Comment: @Cooper This is for google form not any spreadsheets. I have considered doing this through functions on the Responses sheet, however, I prefer to do it with code.

Comment: @Saddles in other words again. 
recipient_classes = [a,b,c,d]
Or [a,b,d] or [c,d] or [b]

I just want to be able to check which options are selected. If A is selected output A is true, and/or if B is selected output B is true, and/or if C is selected output C is true, and/or it D is selected output D is true.

Comment: `This is for google form not any spreadsheets.` That would be a (understandable but regrettable) mistake. 1st, there is no trigger for Google Forms that executes when a response has been received; OTOH, if the form is linked to a spreadsheet, then the spreadsheet DOES have an installable `onFormSubmit` trigger. 2nd, the Event Objects that you are using are ONLY available to the spreadsheet. The script goes in the linked spreadsheet and is triggered when a form response is received.

Comment: `I want to check if A is checked OR B is checked, OR C is checked, etc.` Based on your snapshot, it appears that the form uses `checkboxes` for this question. That would be a problem because `checkboxes` allow respondents to select multiple options (e.g., A **and** B **and** C). A better type would be `multiple choice` since this will allow respondents to select only _one_ choice from the options offered (e.g. A **or** B **or** C).

Comment: @Tedinoz I am writing the script on the spread sheet that is linked.

Comment: Solved it, please let me know what you think and any potential mistakes/improvements.

Comment: I thought that your question was `I want to check if A is checked OR B is checked, OR C is checked, etc.` In any event, the question doesn't explain how the class dates/times are integrated into email. Also since you are using checkboxes and a user _could_ check A _and_ B _and_ C _and_ D, do you want to send multiple emails to the user, or just a single email.

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking I solved it!
I figured out that the recipient_classes = [a, c, d] is not an array, and I was treating it like one, but recipient_classes[0]=[a, c, d] as a string.

So first thing I did was convert it from a string to an array using:

```
  var list = recipient_classes[0]
  var optionsArray = list.split(', ')
```

Then I created an array of all my options with:

```
var total_classes = 4
var class_1 = "Hadith Class - Sunday: 1:00 - 5:00 PM"
var class_2 = "Quran Class - Tuesday: 2:00 - 4:00 PM"
var class_3 = "Arabic Class - Thursday: 3:00 - 6:00 PM"
var class_4 = "etc."

var classArray = []

for (var i = 1; i <= total_classes; i++) {
  var currentString1 = eval('class_' + i)
  classArray.push(currentString1)
}
```

I used i, so in the future if more classes want to be added, you would just have to delcare a class_5

Then inside the function SendEmail(e) I used this for loop to compare the two:

```
  for(var i=0; i < (classArray.length); i++){
    for(var z=0; z < (optionsArray.length); z++){
      if (classArray[i] == optionsArray[z]){
        // Debug: console.log(classArray[i], "  :  ", optionsArray[z])
      }
    }
  }
```

This works perfectly (so far)! I honestly was so proud of myself to solve it even though it was a simple fix. Hope this helps anyone, if anyone has any suggestions or questions please do let me know!

Comment: `I figured out that the recipient_classes = [a, c, d] is not an array` Um, no, recipient classes _is_ an array. The namedValues Event Object returns an object; the keys are the questions, and the values are all arrays. Add this line `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))` to your script as the first line of code; then when you submit a form, look at the Executions log and you'll see the details of all the Event Objects.